# XCode 5 source control repository root directory is forbidden

Tags: ios, xcode, svn

I want to use XCode 5 source control, however I can not check out the source code. Suppose the repository URL is: http://abc.com/root/myporj/trunk. When I try to check out the source codes from XCode5, it says I do not have authorization for repository root directory which is: http://abc.com/root/. And this is is true and I only have authorization for http://abc.com/root/myporj/ because the root directory hosts many other projects. Is is possible I still can use the XCode5 source control for my project? I did try to check out in terminal and open the proejct in XCode5, and I can compare the file, but I can't update the files due to the same reason. How to solve it?

Comment: having the same issue. Xcode 5 ruined the SVN handling, it was easy and user friendly in older version of Xcode. frustrated..

Comment: Completely agree. I can no longer use SVN for my projects in Xcode 5.  Is there any way to alert Apple to this?  If they wanted to push me to use another tool for SVN, they are doing a good job of it...  It seems ludicrous, but I might end up using Eclipse for committing iOS source - crazy...